# How do I get the comments on a video that have been liked by the video creator?

Tags: youtube-data-api

For example,
on a video called "B" created by a channel called "A",
is it possible to get a specific comment that "A" has liked?

Currently, I think I can only get the total number of likes for a particular comment on a video called "B" created by a channel called "A".

Comment: Are you also interested in the case that "A" likes a reply from "C" to the comment written by "B" ("B" and "C" can be the same channel) ? In both case I have a workaround but I just want to customize it to your particular needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am also interested in this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Ok, I'll need one to three days to add this to my API. I'll keep you inform but there isn't any technical problem in sight.

Comment: Thank you.
I would like to ask you one point.
Why do you solve my questions?

Comment: Since a few months I solve question related to youtube-data-api tag because I've used it in a few personal projects and I know how painful it is to use it: we don't have that much data access and most of interesting features aren't working as expected. So because I have a bit of time and knowledges and it's the first time I'm making an API, I found that it was a good opportunity to try to solve the YouTube Data API v3 problems. I hope that some days GAFAM will go open-source or empowering those who use their most popular products.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.It's a nice way of thinking.
I will support you.

Comment: just to make sure: you are looking for likes or/and hearts ? A video creator, in comparaison with viewers, can **heart** a comment in addition to the ability to **like** a comment

Comment: For the most part, yes.
What I'm looking for is (1) comments in the comments section of a video that have been liked by the video creator who made the video, and (2) comments on a certain comment that have been liked by the video creator.

In other words.
I want to get which comments were liked by the video creator.

In the youtube data api, you can only get the total number of likes for a comment, including the likes of the video creator.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were talking about hearts. As YouTube well-known web interface doesn't provide people who liked a video, because it may involve privacy issues, I can't make what you are asking for likes. However I can do for hearts, are you still interested about hearts and not likes ?

Comment: I'm sorry.
I misunderstood "like" and "heart".

The "hearts" you are referring to are the "hearts" that A added to the comments made by other users on the videos made by video creator A?

If so, I would like to ask you to retrieve the comments with hearts added by A.

Comment: Exactly for hearts. I'll keep you inform so but this is technically ok.

Comment: There is a bug concerning continuation token which I spend a lot of time to try to solve. I'll give a shot later but maybe I won't be able to work on this for a few days. So the minimum is to share you [the progress I made on my GitHub](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/main/commentThreads.php) If you understand the method faking what happen in your network tab when browsing comments of a video, don't hesitate to finish this feature.

Comment: I see.Thank you very much.
I'll try my best.

Answer (score 0):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/e1a9d221ab866f0f6d20e7cf7a40fad61525b5ea/commentThreads.php) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=VIDEO_ID&order=ORDER (`ORDER` can be either `time` or `relevance`, but note that [this latter returns less comments](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/1#issuecomment-1366357554)), you will get the video comments with the `isHearted` you are looking for in `item["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]["snippet"]["isHearted"]`.

[The YouTube video `mWdFMNQBcjs`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWdFMNQBcjs) is a good video to test this feature of my API because it doesn't have too many comments while having both pagination mechanism for top level comments and answers, in addition to have its *first* comment hearted and pinned. With this video id you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 67,
        "resultsPerPage": 20
    },
    "nextPageToken": "Eg0SC21XZEZNTlFCY2pzGAYy3gIKtAJnZXRfcmFua2VkX3N0cmVhbXMtLUNxVUJDSUFFRlJlMzBUZ2FtZ0VLbFFFSTJGOFFnQVFZQnlLS0FkdEtUa2V3RXhLY2Q3U3NodkZrZnBjbHlYVEZCTUxWV1RmVUdiUWtGbjFoa3FpNUlucVE2ZmMyRVptc1BGbG15UmhCNXo1LWFhTmNWelc0UGFYdGRMYzd0SUVmRlZmYzlmbUN4SktkVXY0MS1FcWZadXNrQnhrc2g4ZjdnUHdpZHpXM2M4SFA3RGJjVjdCZWtLTWwtMHJXa0phVU0zRW9NU05wS0xjZ1o0aHFpRWRabWNENDE0bVFQQkFVRWdVSWhpQVlBQklGQ0lnZ0dBQVNCUWlYSUJnQUVnVUlpU0FZQUJJSENJY2dFQUVZQUJJSENJVWdFQlFZQVJnQiIRIgttV2RGTU5RQmNqczAAeAEoFEIQY29tbWVudHMtc2VjdGlvbg==",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UgzT9BA9uQhXw05Q2Ip4AaABAg",
            "snippet": {
                "topLevelComment": {
                    "kind": "youtube#comment",
                    "etag": "NotImplemented",
                    "id": "UgzT9BA9uQhXw05Q2Ip4AaABAg",
                    "snippet": {
                        "textOriginal": "Twenty-three",
                        "isHearted": true,
                        "authorDisplayName": null,
                        "authorHandle": "@user-wl1ce4xg4j",
                        "authorProfileImageUrls": [
                            {
                                "url": "https:\/\/yt3.ggpht.com\/ytc\/AMLnZu_3pI88H9gEgJtksqziDFfJj3PSO1E-_7Z5Tn_GJtTMyp7wglMOOAuYSEs_u0LR=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                                "width": 48,
                                "height": 48
                            },
                            ...
                        ],
                        "authorChannelId": {
                            "value": "UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ"
                        },
                        "likeCount": "",
                        "publishedAt": "3 weeks ago",
                        "wasEdited": false,
                        "isPinned": true,
                        "authorIsChannelOwner": true,
                        "videoCreatorHasReplied": true,
                        "totalReplyCount": 23,
                        "nextPageToken": "Eg0SC21XZEZNTlFCY2pzGAYygwEaUBIaVWd6VDlCQTl1UWhYdzA1UTJJcDRBYUFCQWciAggAKhhVQ3ZfTHFGSS0wdk1WWWdOUjNUZUIzelEyC21XZEZNTlFCY2pzQAFICoIBAggBQi9jb21tZW50LXJlcGxpZXMtaXRlbS1VZ3pUOUJBOXVRaFh3MDVRMklwNEFhQUJBZw=="
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

As [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) and [Comments: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) there are two [pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) mechanisms:

- the top level pagination (using here

```
Eg0SC21XZEZNTlFCY2pzGAYyiwEKT0FEU0pfaTJYUjJDTWhJQ2ZGWWdoV2NGUkpqWXRDX1FMQVZYVE9JOU1hUjZmQ0tEUDBkcWpacmQzOG5Yc0kwYUFGUnJFTkdkMmpINlZaMlEiESILbVdkRk1OUUJjanMwAXgBKBQwAUIhZW5nYWdlbWVudC1wYW5lbC1jb21tZW50cy1zZWN0aW9u
```

for the `nextPageToken`) browse top level comments

- the answers pagination (using here

```
Eg0SC21XZEZNTlFCY2pzGAYygwEaUBIaVWd6VDlCQTl1UWhYdzA1UTJJcDRBYUFCQWciAggAKhhVQ3ZfTHFGSS0wdk1WWWdOUjNUZUIzelEyC21XZEZNTlFCY2pzQAFICoIBAggCQi9jb21tZW50LXJlcGxpZXMtaXRlbS1VZ3pUOUJBOXVRaFh3MDVRMklwNEFhQUJBZw==
```

for the `nextPageToken`) browse answers to a given comment