# How can I get comments pinned + favourited via the API?

Tags: youtube-data-api

Using this as support https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Neither Comments nor CommentThreads provide a way to get pinned comments, and comments favourited by the creator. How can I get them?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74936220) solves your problem (cf `isHearted` and `isPinned`).