# Is it possible to get a list of YouTube comments that the creator has replied to?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

As the title says, I'm wondering if it's possible, using the YouTube API, to get a list of comments that the creator has replied to? When on the video itself it seems to show a logo of the creator to imply that they replied.

I've tried to look at the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) but I can't find anything.

Comment: To some extent already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74936220), see `videoCreatorHasReplied` field.